# How to use Blender object rotation style using Maya Navigation?

Tags: 3d-manipulator

I just switched to Blender Navigation to test a few things and shortcuts, and noticed Blender Rotation style is different than Maya, when I press R it goes in Rotation mode, when I press R again it goes in trackball rotation mode I can see this could be useful in some situations, but how do I use this in Maya Navigation 
mode, any shortcut or command for this ?

[image: Trackball Rotation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in any manipulator mode (Translate, Rotate, Scale) when clicking on an axis to start movement and then pressing R one time it will switch to Blender Rotation style, pressing R again will switch to Trackball Rotation style.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it work in Maya, but in Blender you have this options:

1: Turn ON "Transformation manipulate"  [image]

2: Use this shortcuts: (I recommend)

- "R" and after "X" = rotation arround X axis in global coordinates
- "R" and after two times "X" = rotation around X axis - in local coordinates
- "R" and after "SHIFT+X" - for rotate around Y and Z axes (no X)

This work for all axes obliviously and for "G" - grab, "S" - scale and "R" - rotation.